# Is there a method to get the google doc editing time?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I have a problem detecting exactly how much time an user spent editing a document from Google Drive (not the difference  between the document creation time and last modified entry of the change). I'm referring at what Microsoft Word is calculating in the Total editing time.

[image]

Is there a solution to help me calculate this using the Google Drive API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Drive SDK doesn't provide edit time at the moment and there are no workarounds I can think of to determine it with the existing functionality.

Comment: I see, I thought I missed something out while I looked over the Google Drive SDK documentation. Well, let's hope that they will add something helpful in this scope in the future.